# How to edit a cell of an array from a function in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have written the following:

```
def clean(row)
  row.each.with_index do |cell, index|
    next if cell.nil?

    # Replace all spaces and non-breakable spaces by regular spaces
    cell.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}*/, ' ')

    # Remove leading and trailing spaces
    cell.strip!

    # Homogenize empty values by setting everything to `nil`
    row[index] = nil if cell.empty?
  end
end
```

The last line of the block is what I'd like to draw your attention. I wanted to know if this is the only way to actually change the value of the related cell of the original row? If not, is there a smarter way to do it?

---

**EDIT**:

Here is the final version using @ascar answer:

```
def clean(row)
 row.map! do |cell|
   if cell.nil? || cell.empty?
     nil
   else
     cell.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}*/, ' ')
     cell.strip!   
     cell.empty? ? nil : cell
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. Though, if you're using ActiveSupport, you can use [String#blank?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) rather than converting and checking blankness yourself, which could clean up the code a bit.

Comment: could you provide a sample of your 'row' object?

Comment: @Adrien Giboire  chaining ! methods is dangerous. e.g. gsub! will return nil and not original string if nothing was replaced.

Comment: @ascar Thanks for the info though I had no problem while I actually have cells where there is nothing for `gsub!` to replace :/ Anyway, I take good notice of your feedback and will do the changes according to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array#map!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21) should do what you want

```
def clean(row) 
 row.map! do |cell|
   if cell.nil? || cell.empty?
     nil
   else
     cell.gsub(/\A\p{Space}*/, ' ').strip
   end
 end
end
```

or use `Array#map` if you want to return the new array and don't edit in place.

Comment: After testing this, it doesn't seem like the original `row` is changed at all. Doesn't ruby create a copy of the `row` before anything even using `map!`?

Comment: ruby creates a copy of the reference when passing it to a method, but that is still pointing to the same object. So `map!` still changes the content of the original row object (array). i tried it in irb and the contents of the passed row object changed according to your method. Can you provide error or more detail on what you did? if you have direct references to the cells anywere, they will be left unchanged by this method as gsub/strip will return new copies of them. if also editing the cell in place is a requirement your code is probably cleaner.

Comment: You're definitely right. I just got confused because your method isn't doing the same thing as mine. Anyway, thanks, `map!` does the job :) I'll edit my question with the final solution.

Comment: well the only difference was that I did not change the original cell objects but return edited copies of them. but as I said if you really need the same cell objects and not copies of them your original method was probably better way to do it, that required wasn't a part of your question though.